# Userland usb wifi connection

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, usb, vpn

i would like to connect a wifi usb adapter to access the internet through a vpn/ssh (to route all the wifi traffic to the vpn) without root access, idealy with using only "userland" applications (i am using debian). 
I would like to avoid using the built in kernel networking system, for adding a security layer, and moreover i cannot use root privilidges to mess up with the networking settings.
I have a very strong feeling that something like this is more than possible
(essentially a userland recration of some of the netowkring apparatus of the kernel) but my techical comptence is not so advanced.
Do you have any suggestions?
[Proposed Solution vs Solution using kernel networkig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn2z0.png)
Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Connecting to Wi-Fi and setting up a VPN should be possible without root. What is your problem exactly?

Comment: I would like to route all the traffic from the wifi (usb) to the vpn, without having the packets go through the kernel stack, to maximize security

Comment: so please edit the question to reflect that, regardless of its inherent lack of logic.

Comment: While i edit the question, could you please elucidate the "inherent lack of logic"? Morever, connecting without root, means that i do not wish to root privilidges to make the route

Comment: You can replace "illogical" for "totally misunderstanding how this work".

Comment: The universe would probably be a better place if you cared to explained it to me (since you care to read the question)

Comment: @Grigoris why do you think it will add an additional layer of security?

Comment: Assuming that the wifi side has "rogue/malicious data". By doing such a setup, these data would be routed to the vpn and outside my local net with a smaller probability of interference. Essentialy, i would like to implement something resembling a different, dedicated machine that plays the role of a wifi hot spot which the sends all the wifi traffic over the vpn outside my local protected network. As i do not have a dedicated different machine, i thought i could "emulate" one using userspace software

Answer (score 0):

An "obvious" solution would be to use a virtual system for handling the usb-> wifi, the wifi->vpn networking, and although this could -depending on the configuration- be considered userspace, does not fit exactly into the "no root" requirement.